# how do javascript get property value

Tags: javascript

Through the following code I can get a plugin object in chrome browser:

```
nav = window.navigator;
detectPlugin = function(pluginName, mimeType) {

    return nav.plugins && nav.plugins[pluginName] && nav.mimeTypes &&   nav.mimeTypes[mimeType] && nav.mimeTypes[mimeType].enabledPlugin ? nav.plugins[pluginName] : false;
};
obj = detectPlugin('Shockwave Flash', 'application/x-shockwave-flash');
```

And I can see the obj's properties through

```
Object.keys(obj)
```

which is

```
["0", "1", "length", "description", "filename", "name"]
```

or I can see these through chrome Console:

```
Plugin {0: MimeType, 1: MimeType, length: 2, description: "Shockwave Flash 13.0 r0", filename: "libpepflashplayer.so", name: "Shockwave Flash", item: function…}
```

And here is something that I don't understand, if I input

```
obj['application/x-shockwave-flash']
```

I get this

```
MimeType {enabledPlugin: Plugin, description: "Shockwave Flash", suffixes: "swf", type: "application/x-shockwave-flash"}
```

I know obj[0] is the property of 'MimeType', but I don't know why "obj['application/x-shockwave-flash']" can get this.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) only returns

> a given object's own enumerable properties

i.e. if it's inherited or non-enumberable, you won't see it

---

> What does it mean for a property to be enumerable?

In *JavaScript*, you can think of it as similar to meaning "the property is visible to loops"

> What does it mean for a property to be inherited?

An *Object* inherits properties and methods from it's *prototype*, this means you can have very generic *Objects*, e.g. `{} instanceof Object; // true` and very complicated ones like `d = new Date()`, where `d instanceof Date; // true` but it still has everything the from the more generic *Object*, i.e. `d instanceof Object; // true`

---

Consider this (assuming *IE 9+*)

```
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, 'foo', {value:"bar", enumerable:false});
Object.keys(o); // []
o.foo; // "bar"
```

And

```
navigator.plugins[0].hasOwnProperty('application/x-shockwave-flash'); // true

Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
    navigator.plugins[0],
    'application/x-shockwave-flash'
);
//Object {value: MimeType, writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
```

The MDN page [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) may be helpful in understanding *enumerability* and *ownership*

Comment: +1, though this requires IE > 8. Also, `enumerable` defaults to `false` IIRC.